# How do i find a witch hut in Minecraft Pocket Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have never seen a witch hut before(untill now)so how do i find a witch hut in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Answer (score 1):

Witches were added to Pocket Editon in version 0.14, and like in PC, witches can spawn anywhere, as long as the light level is under 7. They can also spawn when lightning hits a village.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Witch

Witch Huts, **spawn in Swamps**, so you might want to go looking for a swamp. However, from my experience, you might not find a witch huts for hours by searching.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Generated_structures#Witch_hut

The best way I find, to find witches, is to go to a large open plain in the middle of the night, and run around for mobs to spawn. Having a witch spawn is plain random chance, but you're bound to see one sooner or later.

Comment: Erm.. He asks about Witch HUTS, not witches by themselves.

Comment: @PanV I put in information about witch huts, too...